# How do I find the worm-riding manual pages?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

If the rest of the quest is any indication, finding these pages is going to cut some more time off of my long wander in the desert. Are they like the stone rose, and I just have to adventure to find them, or are they like the black paint that I could buy from the Black Market (and thus use no adventures?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Worm Riding Manual Pages](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Worm-riding_manual_page) drop after combat in the Arid, Extra Dry Desert. There doesn't seem to be any way to speed it up, but increasing your item drop percentage sometimes appeases RNGesus.

However, they are not mandatory to complete the desert (though they are pretty fun). Every adventure in the desert explores it 1% more, and you can improve on that percentage  each turn by equipping an [UV resistant compass](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/UV-resistant_compass). Also remember to stay [Ultrahydrated](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Ultrahydrated) by visiting the Oasis next door.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain Worm-riding manual pages after combat in The Arid, Extra-Dry Desert. Where after combat is ended (even if the Stomping Boots are used) there is a chance for 1-3 pages to drop.

So to directly answer your question, you will need to adventure (in The Arid, Extra-Dry Desert) to find them.

Pre October 29, 2013 they could only be obtained by a non-combat adventure in an Oasis.